# Using WWAN on elementary OS

Tags: networking

on my Lenovo Thinkpad X220 I have a WWAN module build in.

```
0bdb:1911 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV
```

On Ubuntu (also Windows, but this doesn't matter) it is possible to use the network manger to configure this device. Is it possible to configure and/or to enables and disable it via elementary OS?

It wouldn't be a problem to configure it with a text file but it would be nice to open and close the connection via network manager.